# In SQL Server 2008 R2 - why can't I change the sa credentails

Tags: sql-server-2008, authentication, sa

I'm using AMAZON cloud with SQL Server 2008 R2 installed. I tried to create a password to `sa` and saved it. But when I went back to SQL Server (after I closed SQL Server and opened it again) it does not let me enter it with the sa credentials that I sat. (I can gain access using Windows Authentication)  , stating

> Login failed for user 'sa'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

The error number is 18456. I can go in only with Windows Authentication. How can I set `sa` properly ? Any Ideas?

Here is the full text:

> Cannot connect to [server name].
>
> Login failed for user 'sa'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> Server Name: [server name]
>   Error Number: 18456
>   Severity: 14
>   State: 1
>   Line Number: 65536

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should have also given you a state code as well; searching the combination will show you exactly what the issue is. Are you sure you enabled mixed mode authentication when installing? This article shows you how to enable it: [SQL 2008 R2: Enabling Mixed Mode Authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

This code will verify whether it has been configured for mixed mode authentication already:

```
SELECT CASE SERVERPROPERTY('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly')   
WHEN 1 THEN 'Windows Authentication'   
WHEN 0 THEN 'Windows and SQL Server Authentication'   
END as [Authentication Mode]
```

Comment: The sql was installed by AMAZON. The state code is 1. I edited the question again to include the full error message

Comment: I've updated the answer, run that code to see what auth mode Amazon have put the server in; I have a feeling they have gone for increased security of Windows only...

Comment: Hi Inspired, the result from the query is :Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it right. First I followed "SQL 2008 R2: Enabling Mixed Mode Authentication"  link that Inspired has provided me. Second I opended the EC2 CONSOLE, choosed my Instance and choosed "action" -> "reboot". that's it. Thank you Inspired for your help.